# implementing a template tag within a generic app - django

Tags: django, django-templates

I have developed some code that builds on the contrib comments app, such as handlers for ajax requests. This code is in a separate application, which we can call 'comments2'. the url configuration of the project is structured in such a way that all calls to /comments are directed to this app's views. This works without problems.

Very recently I made a new page that shows comments flagged as inappropriate.

I conceived that it was best done by writing an inclusion templatetag, and wrote one. It works like this:

```
{% display_flagged_comments 'market' %}
```

This tag is placed inside the main app's relevant template.

As seen in the code above, I pass what model (**Market** in this case) the comments belongs to so that the comments2 app remains generic.

I have three issues here that I need guidance on:

First, I feel that the model argument being inside quotes (**'market'**) make the code somewhat less elegant. In the code the argument is converted to a model:

```
#template tag
def show_comments(modelname):
    model = ContentType.objects.get(model=modelname)
    ... # get comments and return them
```

Second, since all requests with **/comments** are directed to comment2 app, I need to devise a different url for this page (it sits inside the main app), such as /managecomments. I find doing that also inelegant.

Third, I want to know if I followed a correct path or is there a better way to implement what I'm trying to do.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The ContentTypeManager has somewhat solved your first problem for you. You can use the method `get_for_model`, which accepts both a class or an instance. Read more at [the contettypes docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#the-contenttypemanager).